# How to move down x axis labels when x axis cross y axis at zero in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I built a barchart with positive and negative values, it looks like this

[image]

however, I need the x-axis to intersect at zero, and when I set the CrossAt parameter to 0, it looks like this

[image]

Can I make the x-axis labels remain as in the first graph?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please also include your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by either ...

Adding a 2nd series and set the value to 0, then set the series chart type to line

OR

Add a strip line to the axis and set the value to 0